# Why does PHP add "\r\n" to an empty string?

Tags: php, rest, request

I’m trying to implement a simple service in PHP. The service needs to return strings to certain requests. However, when I try to echo the string, PHP somehow adds `\r\n` to the beginning of the string. I am using `echo` to output the response.

I tried to echo one space character:

```
$test = ' '; 
echo $test;
```

and in the response I still got `'\r\n'`.

I have tried `header('Content-type: text');` and `$string = preg_replace("\r\n", "", $string);`, but I’m still getting the new line in the response.

I’m new to PHP, so if this is some kind of concept, could someone provide me with pointers to information where I can read about it?

Comment: You're printing `test` not `$test`. There is a missing `$`.

Comment: @EthanBierlein except, not. while php does have some wonky/nonstandard behavior, it doesn't magically prepend `\r\n` to strings.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It's possible this character is in your sourcecode somewhere, for instance at the end of one your scripts, like: `?>\r\n`.

A best practice is to never include the final `?>` in each file to avoid accidental output.

This recommendation is in the [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) Coding Style Guide.

> The closing `?>` tag MUST be omitted from files containing only PHP.

It's also in the [manual](http://php.net/basic-syntax.phptags).

> If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.

Comment: Exactly what was going on.

Comment: Also be wary of the sneaky space before the open tag: `<?php` ! You wouldn't be the first to waste time to that sneaky problem

Comment: are you serious? never include the closing tag is the best practice?

Comment: The same mythical characters could appear when using include or require other file (as config), even when file encodings match.

Comment: @EliranMalka yes it is.

Comment: to be honest , I never understood PHP properly and I've some deep respect for developers who work with large codebases and keep themselves sane. and then there is Laravel.

Comment: @EliranMalka as the OP said - "If a file is pure PHP code".

Comment: @Martijn I had a return before <?php in one of my classes, thanks for the tip!

Comment: `"It's possible this character is in your sourcecode somewhere, for instance at the end of one your scripts, like: ?>\r\n"` Thank u so much! I was not being able to find what was happening because everything was working fine. So reading your answer I noticed I had written somethings after the code with comments. I deleted it but php was reading the white spaces yet.